# PDF file is not opening in new tab in blazor .net core

Tags: javascript, .net-core, blazor, pdf-generation, blazor-webassembly

In my `wwwroot` folder I have a `PDF` template that I edit with `iTextSharp`. My `PDF` is saved in the `wwwroot` folder and I return a complete path to it when downloaded from my system.

I want to be able to view the `PDF` in a new tab using `Blazor` `.NET Core`. Below is the path that is generated through code, which is combined path of local & server:

```
E:\Latest\XYZ\Blazer.Net\Web\XYZ\app\wwwroot/Pages/Reports/AppointmentManager/Forms/MRInvoice/9e5cfd36-9fe2-4304-962e-e9b61f6584a6.pdf
```

I tried to open this `PDF` into the next tab through JavaScript `function window.open` but it doesn't work.

Is there a precise solution available out there using `Blazor` `.NET Core`?